# Drag file out of Electron App and drop anywhere where accepted

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have been at this for hours and re-tried in may different ways.

I am working on an app that grabs a random file (.mid) and allows the user to play it. If the user likes it there is a div with an id of "dragToDAW". Upon clicking and dragging on this div I would like the user to be able to see an icon being dragged along with the file contents/path to drop into a DAW or if they drop it in a file browser the file will copy there too. That last one is not a necessity.

I have this:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

document.getElementById('dragToDAW').ondragstart = (event) => {
    console.log('dragstart', currentMidiFilePath);
    event.preventDefault();
    ipc.send('ondragstart', currentMidiFilePath);
};
```

And this:

```
    ipcMain.on('ondragstart', (event, filePath) => {
        console.log(filePath);
        event.sender.startDrag({
            file: filePath,
            icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/images/midi-file.png')
        });
    })
```

But it never fires anything. There are also no errors in any console.

Any guidance or snippet would be appreciated.